# RN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped

Tags: apache-spark

I installed spark and set all the environment variable properly of spark and python as also mentioned in `stackoverflow` but still getting this warning on starting spark

```
20/09/06 13:33:52 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. The reason is that environment variables are not set up properly. Earlier what I was doing is just clicking on the "**Enter**" when the warning comes, and the process continued from the next line without any issues. Though it is a temporary solution but it worked.

Another solution which worked for me permanently is to configure environment/PATH variables properly.

```
Steps:

1. Make sure to have py4j zip file available. My py4j was in the directory, 
   "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib".
2. Now, Go to Environment Variables.
3. Go to PATH in user variables.
4. Click on Edit, and Now add these path as a new. 
5. %SPARK_HOME%\bin
6. %SPARK_HOME%\python
7. %SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-(version number)-src.zip, mine was 0.10.9
   so I typed, %SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
8. Finally add, %PYTHONPATH%
```

Click on OK, and save all changes. Rerun the program it should work properly.